Cause-Effect Events in accelerated frames
How can we be sure that timelike events maintain their cause-effect relationship in accelerating reference frames, given that the definition of time ordering in special relativity is based on inertial frames? Does time ordering need to be re-verified for accelerating frames, and if not, why?

Observers that are accelerating know that they are accelerating and thus know that they have to account for their own acceleration before they can make sense of causality.

The causal structure is one of the things that is encoded in the spacetime metric. Whether there exists a possible timelike link between two events (and therefore whether they can causally influence each other) is independent of whatever coordinates are used to represent the spacetime metric (connected to the local frame of a specific observer or not).
Note that in general relativity observer frames are local and do not necessarily have a unique global extension. Consequently, they do not play as central a role as in special relativity.
